# How to stop Central Admin People Picker from showing results for both trusted identity provider and its associated claim provider

Tags: 2013, people-picker, claim-provider

I have a trusted identity provider which is associated with a claims provider.

`Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer`shows that `ClaimProviderName` is set to match the custom claims provider.

This appears to be sufficient to give the expected search results when using the claims picker under e.g. `site -> People and Groups -> Site Members` as follows[image]:

However, if I access the people picker under Central Administration (e.g. when managing administrators for a Secure Store target application), I get a different picker, which includes both of the expected results, but *additionally* shows spurious results for whatever happens to be typed in under the trusted identity provider:

These entries are correct:
[image]

However, this entry is incorrect - there is no "vogon" user, and the trusted identity provider shouldn't even be showing results directly, since it is associated with a claims provider:
[image]

How do I get the People Picker in Central Admin to honor the ClaimsProvider association for a trusted identity provider?

Comment: what is authentication method associated with Central Admin?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Central Admin is using Windows Authentication (NTLM)

Comment: We experience the exact same problem and would appreciate some help. Did this ever get solved by you and if so, how?

Comment: @Gerald Have you installed SharePoint 2013 Service Pack (and run the SharePoint 2013 Products Configuration Wizard as the second step of applying the update after the updates are installed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Service Pack 1 for SharePoint 2013, or one of the updates after it has fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

We patched to Service Pack 1 and CU April 2015 and it does the trick. Thank you very much!